# php variable variablename in class

Tags: php, class, variables, dynamically-generated

Could anyone tell me how to use variable variables in classes:

```
    <?php

    class test
    {
        // set default values;
        private $type = '';
        private $var = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        // add element to array
        $this->var[] = 'abc';

        // set $type to make it dynamically accessible
        $this->type = 'var';
    }

    public function bar()
    {
        // return variable $var;
        return $this->$type; // should give array([0]=>'abc') BUT give 'Undefined variable: type'  and 'Cannot access empty property';
    }
}                                                                                      
    $class = new test;
    var_dump($class->bar());
    ?>
```

So `$this->type` should be dynamically and return the "value" of its name, in this case this was the value of 'var', which is a variable with value '`array(...)`'.

Comment: where you call these methods bar(),foo()

Comment: Of course I could set temporary variables in method scope but is it possible without this "detour"?

Comment: In global scope. I edited.

Comment: there is no Closing brace of class test in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(`type` is also a class property so you have to use `$this`)

```
return $this->{$this->type};
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => abc )
```

**EDIT:**

You can read more about why I used `{}` in the manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: What's the purpose of using the `{` and `}` in `$this->{$this->type}; `? I see them used from time to time, but I have no idea why.

Comment: Thanks for this information, I didn't know `{$var}` yet!

Comment: @AndreiP. Well because of various reasons: 1. Since we use class properties for variable variables it tries this: `$this->$this` So it tries to convert the object to a string which it wants to access, but this doesn't work that's the first and main reason 2. If OP wants to access a specific array element then he can just put `[X]` behind it. (Otherwise with things like: `$$a[1]` you will get problems) 3. For readability I do this

Comment: @Rizier123 Ah, I see now. I don't really use variable variables a lot(read: never). And got a bit confused on what was going on. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

when you are accessing the variable defined inside any function of the class 
Do this:

`$this->variable_name`

without $

not like this

```
$this->$variable_name
```

Comment: I added `$` to access the variable with the name of `variable_name`'s value. I didn't know the `{$var}` solution.